# On plugging in my iPhone to the car stereo, music plays automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, audio, music

I have a Sony head unit in my car that has a USB socket and no Bluetooth. When I plug in my iPhone 5C running iOS 10.3.3 into the USB, it starts playing music from my iTunes library automatically.

I do not have a iTunes Match or Apple Music subscription. Neither do I have my credit card linked to the iTunes Store, which could cause accidental subscription to the service.

I do not have any songs synced to the device from my iTunes Library.
I haven't used iTunes Wi-Fi Sync in a long while.

[image]
[image]

I have a 4G data connection active on my iPhone while in the car.

I have turned off automatic Music download from iTunes Store.
Mobile Data is turned off for music and there is Zero KB of download music.

[image]
[image]

But as soon as I plug in my iPhone, it starts playing some random song. I fail to understand how this could be happening?

[image]

Where is the iPhone getting the music track from? There is no Wi-Fi connection as I am in the car. It sometimes plays a random track from my iTunes library. How do I tell the phone to **delete** whatever information it has about my iTunes library without screwing up the link between it and my Mac for everything else?

Comment: Is that a default track in itunes just as an example?

Comment: Most questions are about « when I plug my phone in, it won’t play... »

Comment: What happens if you put it in airplane mode? I can see it says you have 0 songs, but have you opened iTunes and checked if these songs are on your phone?

Comment: @Christian iTunes is not on my phone - I deleted its app icon and the music icon long ago.

Comment: Do you have any other music apps? If you tap the album image it should open up whatever app is playing the music. Some web browsers can play videos like this as well.